# The standard library is still required with `default-features = false` on bincode

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, cargo-features

I'm trying to use the bincode crate. As it's default features, it uses the standard library, but I'm working in a `no_std` environment. I've added `default-features = false` to my Cargo.toml, but it still doesn't compile.

My dependencies:

```ini
[package]
name = "fsys"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
bincode = { version = "1.3.3", default-features = false}
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. The `std` feature of `bincode` is disabled, yet it still tries to build it's dependencies with the standard library.

Here's the shorter version of the error message:

```
   Compiling serde v1.0.182
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `x86_64-cos` target may not support the standard library
  = note: `std` is required by `serde` because it does not declare `#![no_std]`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`
```

The original error message is this, but followed by 20K lines of failed `std` imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bincode`](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) does not have the `std` feature flag in version `1.3.3`, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/bincode-org/bincode/blob/v1.3.3/Cargo.toml).

You probably want to use [version `2.0.0`](https://crates.io/crates/bincode/2.0.0-rc.3) which is only available as a release candidate at the moment, but offers support for [`#![no_std]`](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/intro/no-std.html).

Comment: I got confused, because I thought that bincode does support no_std, but now I've realized that I was looking at the trunk branch on github